# Is Megavalanche suitable for beginners?

Tags: mountain-bike, full-suspension

I have a huge desire to attend on Megavalanche in France, but I don't know if I am good enough. I don't ride park and only do descents from the local mountains where you "need" a full suspension bike (I have a Giant Trance 3 enduro bike). I can ride anything, except 2 meter drops.

Megavalanche is pretty hardcore. Does anyone know any similar (not downhill, but events with more descent than ascend) in Austria or Italy?

Comment: It might not be for you, Henry Ford said 'Whether you think you can, or you think you can't--you're right.', It possible he had a dream about a future spot we now call DH mountain biking.

Comment: Why do you think so? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEKB7clgC_A

Comment: It doesn't look so hard.

Comment: just gotta go for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mega is not a single mass-start race. There are qualification stages on the days preceding the main event.

You might get an entry into the Mega, but if you don't qualify, that's a very expensive learning experience!

Comment: I think I saw a Youtube video where it was mentioned that everyone that signs up gets to race on the main track on the day between the qualification and the finals. Have they since changed that?

Comment: No, but do you consider that to be "racing the Megavelanche"?

Comment: That wouldn't seem to matter if you're not expecting a single- or double-digit placement. OP will still get the experience of a race down the main track, even if they fail miserably in the qualifier round, which is the sort of detail that could matter to a beginner.

Comment: Thanks! Do you maybe know any Enduro events for beginners in Austria?